# jQuery not available to other scripts

Tags: theme-development, jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I'm getting console errors that "jQuery is not a function" even though:

a) it IS being enqueued correctly and called in the header

b) it IS listed as a dependency for the scripts that are enqueued.

I've reverted to older versions of WordPress (now back to 4.8), I've disabled and enabled plugins as well with none of that working.

I don't understand how jQuery is called correctly on the page but other scripts aren't able to use it as a function?

Site is http://www.obair.stevenkellow.com/ for reference

Comment: The console should give you clues where the offending lines of code are. Without knowing that we here can only guess. The problem might be completely unrelated to wordpress.

Comment: The console errors are essentially showing jQuery isn't there - wherever a plugin is trying to use jQuery it returns a console error, so it's not pinpointing where the error is with jQuery itself unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two copies of some inline script

```
var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

inside a commented section 'mc_embed_signup'. The 'true' here is [`removeAll`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/#jQuery-noConflict-removeAll):

> removeAll
>   Type: Boolean
>   A Boolean indicating whether to remove all jQuery variables from the global scope (including jQuery itself).

You should track down this script and try and understand what it's trying to do, or just remove the 'true' if you're sure you don't need it.

Comment: Wasn't exactly why but helped me find the culprit: was including an external MailChimp verification library that was calling it's own copy of jQuery and conflicting with WordPress' copy. Thanks for the help!